# Disabling write access for all USB devices except for specific device IDs?

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-registry

I manage over 500 laptops that need USB write access disabled except to a specific USB drive my company provides.

I know about adding the WriteProtect entry to the registry to prevent write access to all USB drives. This edit works wonderfully but it prevents our USB drive being written to as well. Is there a way to add device IDs to the registry to give those devices Read/Write access *(not to be confused with installation permission)* while simultaneously keeping all other USB devices as Read only?

If it’s not possible to do through the registry I am also open to the idea of using secure/safe third-party software that could also do the trick.

Edit: I should mention these laptop's are in the field across the country, run Windows 7 Professional, and not apart of any domain.

Comment: See this utility, it says it can disable by device...http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

Comment: Because the USB standards have devices "self identify", it is difficult to lock down ports through software. See http://gizmodo.com/watching-a-usb-hack-in-action-makes-me-never-want-to-le-1672704228. Some companies are resorting to epoxying the ports! http://www.slashgear.com/usb-vulnerability-fix-includes-using-epoxy-07349636/

Comment: Well it's not that we want to deny access to USB devices, we only want to deny Write Access to all USB devices, except the one we provide. We deal in PHI, so only our approved USB device is allow to have files written to it. Other USB devices need to be allowed in a read-only mode as to copy data from them, but we don't have control on when and where those USB devices are required to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you're using Server 2008 and higher, take a look at the below that can be achieved through group policy.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731387.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is directed towards controlling device installation. I'm looking to control Read/Write access. All USB devices are Read Only with only a specific device ID being Read/Write enabled.